# Cisco IOS -- How do I make the console prompt for a password upon serial line session 0 connection?

Tags: cisco, switch, ethernet, cisco-ios, cli

I'm using Putty to connect via a serial connection to the console. I have a `line con 0` password set, as shown by `show running-config`. I close this session (via Putty), reconnect, and the CLI prompt shows the last state I was in (in enable mode), and it does not prompt for a password.

I went into configuration -> line console 0 -> login local and it just returns the root with no indication that this command took effect. Either way, when I restart the session, it still does not prompt for password.

How can I get a serial session to prompt for a password at the start of a serial session, and how do I refresh the serial session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YLearn is correct in that you are not properly disconnecting the session. If I understand the way you have this configured (password on the line, `login local` on the line, and no global username and password configured), when you properly disconnect the session by `exit`, you will find yourself locked out of the router. If you use `login local` it doesn't look for the password under the line configuration.

[Telnet, Console and AUX Port Passwords on Cisco Routers Configuration Example](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ios-nx-os-software/ios-software-releases-110/45843-configpasswords.html#pw-line)

> ## Configure Passwords on the Line
>
> To specify a password on a line, use the **password** command in line
>   configuration mode. To enable password checking at login, use the
>   **login** command in line configuration mode.
>
> **Note:** To find additional information on the commands used in this document, use the Command Lookup Tool (registered customers only).
>
> ### Configuration Procedure
>
> In this example, a password is configured for all users attempting to
>   use the console.
>
> 1. From the privileged EXEC (or "enable") prompt, enter configuration
>      mode and then switch to line configuration mode using the following
>      commands. Notice that the prompt changes to reflect the current
>      mode.
>
>    ```
>    router#configure terminal
>    Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.
>    router(config)#line con 0
>    router(config-line)#
>    ```
> 2. Configure the password, and enable password checking at login.
>
>    ```
>    router(config-line)#password letmein
>    router(config-line)#login
>    ```
> 3. Exit configuration mode.
>
>    ```
>    router(config-line)#end
>    router#
>    %SYS-5-CONFIG_I: Configured from console by console
>    ```
>
>    **Note:** Do not save configuration changes to **line con 0** until your ability to log in has been verified.
>
> **Note:** Under the line console configuration, login is a required configuration command to enable password checking at login. Console
>   authentication requires both the **password** and the **login**
>   commands to work.

This is how to use `login local` command:

> ## Configure Local User-Specific Passwords
>
> To establish a username-based authentication system, use the
>   **username** command in global configuration mode. To enable password checking at login, use the **login local** command in line
>   configuration mode.
>
> ### Configuration Procedure
>
> In this example, passwords are configured for users attempting to
>   connect to the router on the VTY lines using Telnet.
>
> 1. From the privileged EXEC (or "enable") prompt, enter configuration
>      mode and enter username/password combinations, one for each user for
>      whom you want to allow access to the router:
>
>    ```
>    router#configure terminal
>      Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.
>      router(config)#username russ password montecito
>      router(config)#username cindy password belgium
>      router(config)#username mike password rottweiler
>    ```
> 2. Switch to line configuration mode, using the following commands.
>      Notice that the prompt changes to reflect the current mode.
>
>    ```
>    router(config)#line vty 0 4
>    router(config-line)#
>    ```
> 3. Configure password checking at login.
>
>    ```
>    router(config-line)#login local
>    ```
> 4. Exit configuration mode.
>
>    ```
>    router(config-line)#end
>    router#
>    %SYS-5-CONFIG_I: Configured from console by console
>    ```
>
> **Note:** In order to disable auto Telnet when you type a name on the CLI, configure **no logging preferred** on the line that is used.
>   While **transport preferred none** provides the same output, it also
>   disables auto Telnet for the defined host that are configured with the
>   **ip host** command. This is unlike the **no logging preferred** command, which stops it for undefined hosts and lets it work for the
>   defined ones.

Comment: Depends on how AAA is setup (or *not* setup)

Comment: I had asked for a full running configuration, but that was ignored.

Comment: That more meant for people who find this answer via Google. AAA complicates things (esp. where RADIUS and TACACS+ get involved.)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are just disconnecting and reconnecting. Disconnecting is not a "hang up" and does not cause the user on console to logoff.

Use the "exit" command to log off and you should be prompted for the password.

This is also why you always want to set the "exec-timeout" on your lines. Otherwise, if someone connects to the console and forgets to log off, someone else may come along after them, connect and get access they shouldn't.